# Python: How to check if the string contains number from a specific range

Tags: python, regex, string, pattern-matching

I've a long list of strings; they are basically filenames. The format is like:

```
["abcdedf_023.txt",
 "foeoioo_011.txt", 
 "sdjskdsjd_3131.txt", 
 "dsdsdsrer_044.txt", 
 "rgfbfgrt_12.txt"]
```

and so on.

What I need is to filter out the names containing numbers greater than `15` at the end. So with the above input, the desired outout would be:

```
["abcdedf_023.txt",
 "sdjskdsjd_3131.txt", 
 "dsdsdsrer_044.txt"]
```

This number (15) is not fixed and provided by user as input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like below? Just use `\d+` to search numbers?

```
[i for i in l if int(re.search('\d+', i).group(0)) > 15]
```

Demo:

```
["abcdedf_023.txt", "sdjskdsjd_3131.txt", "dsdsdsrer_044.txt"]
```

---

You can also search for `_(\d+).txt` (use `()` to catch the numbers like):

```
[i for i in f if int(re.search('_(\d+).txt', i).group(1)) > 15]
```

To remove something like `"abc122dedf_01.txt"` in your file (if you don't want it).

---

If you only need the last two numbers in the filenames, for example get `03` from `1203`:

```
[i for i in f if int(re.search('\d+', i).group(0)[-2:]) > 15]
```

Comment: I think I would need to remove underscore '_' before converting the search result to integer?

Comment: @user2436428: Nope, I'm using [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) in my code. So it will keep searching unless it find a integer.

Comment: @user2436428: If there's other integers before that `_`, and you wish you could ignore them, try the second or the third solution.

Comment: I am talking about this statement:
int(re.search('_(\d+).txt', i).group(0))

Comment: @user2436428: Oh, my bad. As you can see I'm using `(\d+)` to catch the integers, but I forgot change `.group(0)` to `.group(1)`. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `split`

```
>>> l = ["abcdedf_023.txt",
"foeoioo_011.txt", 
"sdjskdsjd_3131.txt", 
"dsdsdsrer_044.txt", 
"rgfbfgrt_12.txt"]
>>> [i for i in l if int(i.split('.')[0].split('_')[-1]) > 15 ]
['abcdedf_023.txt', 'sdjskdsjd_3131.txt', 'dsdsdsrer_044.txt']
```

Replace `15` in the above list comprehension with the variable which actually contains the number you want to check with.. Note that the variable must be of type interger or convert it to `int` during  condition checking.